# React router with regex - inserting a number in middle of the path

Tags: reactjs, string, react-router-dom

I get my current path by using `useLocation()` hook.

I have several buttons and want them to navigate me to the **current path combined with that concrete list ID.**

Lets suppose its `https://localhost:3000/list/3/items`

How to insert that **ID** (here is 3) in between - list/**{id}**/items - with regex?

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const location = useLocation();

  // location.pathname - getting current path

  // pinned to each button
  const handleListChange = (listId: number) => {
    // navigate(...);
  };
```

I cant achieve that with just `navigate("/list/{listId}/items")` because `/items` can differ depending on what subpage im currently at (`"/list"` stays the same). So it can be for example `list/{listId}/itemsSubpage/.../...`. I just want to stay at the current page when navigating and only let id change.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply redirect starting from the root? I don't see the need for a regular expression here.

```
  navigate(`/list/${listId}/items`);
```

or am I missing something?

---

**Post Edit answer:**

There are a few ways to achieve what you want but I'll just go ahead and post the one that came to me first, you can adjust it to your needs.

```js
const exp = /(\/list\/)\d{1,}(\/?.+)?$/i;
const currentUrlMock = 'https://test.com/list/240/items/subpage/2/doesnt-matter'
const replaceId = (newId) => currentUrlMock.replace(exp, `$1${newId}$2`)

console.log(replaceId(3)); 
// logs: https://test.com/list/3/items/subpage/2/doesnt-matter
```

How this works is that the regular expression contains two capture groups:

`(\/list\/)` that matches the `/list` part 
`(\/?.+)?$` that matches everything that appears after your ID

Between them there's a `\d{1,}` that will capture all digits, it's not a capture group though - it has no parentheses around it `()`.

Replace method on string accepts regex as a first param and in the second param you can access captured groups by using dollar signs and group number, `$1` to capture first group, `$2` to capture the second group and so on.

By using `$1${newId}$2` $1 will be replaced with fist captured group - `/list` and $2 will be replaced with second captured group - `(\/?.+)?$`. Between these a new ID which is passed in a function param will be inserted.

You should add more checks to make sure there's a proper match, I also tested the regular expression only for these URLs:

- https://test.com/list/4
- https://test.com/list/4/
- https://test.com/list/120
- https://test.com/list/120/
- https://test.com/list/120/items
- https://test.com/list/120/items/240
- https://test.com/list/120/items/240/

and it works for these but your real use case might be different.

Comment: I edited my question. The route can differ depending on the subpage i am currently at, e.g.: ```list/{listId}/itemsSubpage/.../...``` . So it cant be a hard-coded path. The only thing that remains the same is ```list/``` at the start.